# Selection of specific physical interface in default UVM register layer sequences

Tags: system-verilog, verification, uvm

In our DUT, we have two separate independent physical interfaces (APB & I2C) (active 1 at a time) through which all registers can can be accessed,

Also in our register model, we created two reg_maps, one for each APB & I2C.

Now through testcase, we want only one physical interface at a time, to be subjected to default uvm sequences (i.e. uvm_reg_access_seq, uvm_reg_bit_bash_seq,etc) but it is not possible as uvm_sequence will get all the maps using get_maps();

So **without over-riding** the default uvm_reg_access_seq, is it possible to achieve such type of configuration in testcase itself via using uvm_reg_map or some other methods.

Kindly refer following pseudo code

```
//Pseudo Code for Scenario
 class  dut_reg_test extends base_test;
  `uvm_component_uti ls(dut_reg_test)

  //Handle of default uvm register access sequence
  uvm_reg_access_seq my_reg_seq;
  // Select Physical Interface
  rand bit APB_I2C;

  uvm_reg_map test_map;
  dut_reg_model regmodel;

  task buid_phase (uvm_phase phase);
    super.build_phase(phase);
    // Select PHY Interface via commandline
      if ($value$plusargs("APB_I2C=%b", APB_I2C))
     else
        APB_I2C = $random;

    if (APB_I2C)
       test_map = regmodel.apb
    else
       test_map = regmodel.i2c
  endtask : build_phase

   task main_phase (uvm_phase phase); 
    //Create method for sequence
    my_reg_seq=uvm_single_access_seq::type_id::create("my_reg_seq");
    //Randomize with selected map
    my_reg_seq.randomize with { maps == test_map;});
    // Start default sequence
     my_reg_seq.start(NULL);
   endtask : main_phase

endclass : dut_reg_test
```

The above strategy cannot be implemented because uvm_reg_access sequence doesn't contain uvm_reg_map it's only present in uvm_reg_single_access_seq,

Similar kind of limitations persists will all uvm_reg_bit_bash_seq & reset sequences.

Can we have some strategy to resolve this issue ?

- Nikunj Hinsu

Comment: I believe, you need to control "add_reg" method through command line argument in the register block, because that will directly affect the get_maps method. So add_reg method should be called only for that register map, which is provided through command line argument (APB or I2C).

Comment: @KaranShah, Controlling "add_reg" might solve the issue over here, but usually the reg_model is generated by either tool or script, so altering it might create some unpredictable issues but not sure. *Thanks 4 comment ,will update after giving a try*

Comment: Yes, reg models are generated by scripts, but in this case, you may change the code to check, whether it works or not.